# change javascript absolute url for @font face to relative url

Tags: javascript, webfonts

Right now with this piece of javascript the url to the woff fonts indicates an absolute url. How do I change this from pointing to an absolute url, to a relative url

```
case 'woff':
        document.write("<style>\n");
                document.write("@font-face {font-family:\"FRHopper430\";src:url(\"" + path + "/webfonts/woff/style_194131.woff\") format(\"woff\");}\n");
                document.write("@font-face {font-family:\"FRHopper431\";src:url(\"" + path + "/webfonts/woff/style_194133.woff\") format(\"woff\");}\n");
                document.write("</style>");
        break;
```

Comment: That depends completely on the URL(s) of the page(s) where that code will run.

Comment: I found the problem I need to set a custom path to correct this